# GCP logs with Docker offline

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-logging

When using the Google Cloud logging driver for Docker, it blocks the container from starting when Docker is offline (which is often the case, but eventually it connects to the internet). The error message:

`failed to initialize logging driver: unable to connect or authenticate with Google Cloud Logging: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 216.58.214.10:443: i/o timeout`

I thought this could be solved with the option `"mode": "non-blocking"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, but no luck.

Does anyone have a way to be able to use the GCP log driver for Docker while offline?

Comment: You can try implementing the GCP Logging driver for docker using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) which uses GCE VM.